# Laravel-5 search certain fields if user input is not empty

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm trying to build a search query using Laravel-5 but I seem to be generating the wrong sql.

Here's the code I am using:

```
BookingDates::where('status', 'Booked')->where('email', Input::get('email'))->where('name', 'like', '%' . Input::get('name') . '%')->where('date', $date)->get();
```

However sometimes the user may not provide an email.  When this happens, this part of the query (`where('email', Input::get('email'))`) should be omitted.  For example, this is the query that would run if they didn't provide an email:

```
BookingDates::where('status', 'Booked')->where('name', 'like', '%' . Input::get('name') . '%')->where('date', $date)->get();
```

Is there an easy/pretty way to do this using Laravel-5?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can build the query in separate steps:

```
$query = BookingDates::where('status', 'Booked')
                     ->where('name', 'like', '%' . Input::get('name') . '%')
                     ->where('date', $date);

if($email = Input::get('email')){
    $query->where('email', $email);
}

$result = $query->get();
```